# Rewrite url generated by a custom made plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a store locator page with the options to choose Country and City. The result page url looks like http://website.com/store-locator/?id=26 where 26 is the id of the country and depending on that the city dropdown changes.

I want to change the url structure to http://website.com/store-locator/?country=usa  so that it is more intuitive.

I tried htaccess but it didn't work. We are saving the country slug as well in the database.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^store-locator/(.*)$ store-locator?slug=$1 [L]
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here? Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the URL `http://website.com/store-locator/?id=26` to `http://website.com/store-locator/?country=usa` programmatically

Then alter the script to recognize `country name` instead of `id`

and in HTACCESS

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^store-locator/?country=(.*)$ store-locator?slug=$1 [L]
```